# Mysql Results not being filter by variable where cell value = Yes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am using Ajax to select an option from a dropdown menu which then places the option selected into a mysql query as the variable

query looks like this:

```
select * from table where VARIABLE = 'Yes';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21afac/3

Here is an SQLfiddle with some example data and i have used nuts in the query to give an idea of how im trying to get the result outcome where nut is the variable replaced by q in the below code.

In the fiddle Nuts returns just 1 result whereas in my actual DB it returns all the rows when i replace Nuts with '".$q."' in my query

The test.php file that im using where the variable is being defined by q and in the dev console it shows q returning as the dropdown option selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password!','DB');
if (!$con) {
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE '".$q."' = 'Yes' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Product'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

my test.html side with the dropdown

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allerg(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="allerg(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
  <option value="Wheat">Wheat</option>
  <option value="Egg">Egg</option>
  <option value="Nuts">Nuts</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You quote strings not column names.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have changed quotations but im staying having the same issue's where am i going wrong ?

Comment: What is this `$q = intval($_GET['q']);`?  Converting to integer will make `$q` = `0`.  `echo $sql;` to see.